# Dividing two calculated values in mySQL select

Tags: mysql

Here's what my query is:

```
SELECT  a.cartodb_id as cartdb_id, a.identifier AS store,
(SELECT count(*) FROM full_data_for_testing_deid_2) ,count(b.*) AS   customer_count 
FROM demo_locations_table a, full_data_for_testing_deid_2 b 
WHERE ST_DWithin(a.the_geom::geography,b.the_geom::geography,16093) 
GROUP BY a.cartodb_id
```

and here's what comes back:

```
| cartdb_id | store           | count | customer_count |
|-----------|-----------------|-------|----------------|
| 1         | Store Number: 1 | 32085 | 30             |
| 2         | Store Number: 2 | 32085 | 283            |
| 3         | Store Number: 3 | 32085 | 609            |
| 4         | Store Number: 4 | 32085 | 61             |
| 5         | Store Number: 5 | 32085 | 325            |
```

In this case, `count` equals the total number of customers (one row per customer) in my table. What I want is another column that is shows the percentage of customers per store: `customer_count` divided by `count`, but I can't figure out how to integrate this into my query. PS: I don't actually need the `count` column. I just included it as reference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.cartodb_id as cartdb_id, a.identifier AS store,
count(b.*) AS   customer_count , count(b.*)/(SELECT count(*) FROM full_data_for_testing_deid_2)*100 as Percentage
FROM demo_locations_table a, full_data_for_testing_deid_2 b 
WHERE ST_DWithin(a.the_geom::geography,b.the_geom::geography,16093) 
GROUP BY a.cartodb_id
```

Comment: Thanks. This runs, but it's not giving me the right results. I think this [`full_data_for_testing_deid_2)/count(b.*)*100`] needs to be reversed (like this: [`count(b.*)/full_data_for_testing_deid_2)*100`], but I'm getting error.

Comment: I believe OP wanted `100*count(b.*) / (SELECT count(*) FROM full_data_for_testing_deid_2)` as the percentage column.

Comment: Yes, @cars10. That did the trick. Thanks. This gives me a rounded number (like 1). Is there a way to make sure this returns a decimal out to a few places (like 1.456)?

Comment: Yes, use `100.` instead of `100`, this way you will get a float result.

Comment: @cars10. Okay...that's pretty awesome. Had no idea you could do that. Am I getting greedy if I ask for this to return the value rounded to 3 places (1.345 v. 1.34534234234)? Tried `100.000`, but that didn't work

Comment: Use `round(val,digits)` ... (not tested, but works in MS-SQL)

Comment: round(count(b.*)/(SELECT count(*) FROM full_data_for_testing_deid_2)*100, 2) as percentage

Comment: @cars10 You're like a magician. Works perfectly in PostgreSQL apparently too!